# Potential error in a physics exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, resonance

My physics textbook has the following exercise:

[image: This is the question]

My grasp on the problem is that the situation is similar to than of an organ pipe closed at one end. As such, standing waves would be set up in the experiment. Since velocity of sound and frequency of the source are constant, the wavelength should remain constant too. Hence the positions of the nodes and antinodes would remain same. So the change in position of cardboard will only decide whether resonant waves are set up or not. If resonant waves are set up, then intensity would increase and decrease according to a pattern in a given position. If not, then the changes in intensity would have no pattern. As such, the question is incorrect.

If I am wrong, please correct me and give me a hint as to how to proceed.

Comment: The question doesn't describe the entire resonance pattern, just 20cm of it. It's still periodic like you say, and the question is basically telling you the period.

Comment: This is not a question about resonance.  It's actually more basic and simple.  It is not the same as an open organ pipe. The pipe has two boundary conditions: a displacement node at the closed end and  a pressure node (hence displacement antinode) at the open end. Hence it will only support certain wavelengths.  This has just one node so there is no constraint on the wavelength of the standing waves.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow,  you are right. But standing waves would be set up since waves are reflected from the cardboard. This complicates things. Any advice on how to solve it?